# Static constants

Tags: c, gcc

Does it make any difference in `C99` when one writes `const int x = 1;` vs. `static const int x = 1;` in a *header* (`*.h`) file?

Comment: I usually prepend static identifier to initializate a variable in a function, so after the first call to that funciton, any other calls won't reinitialize the variable again. The variable acts just like a constant if one tries to reinitialize it. If your variable is declared const, you can never modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cdarke said, it makes a difference.

`const int x = 1;` creates a for the linker visible symbol, for each module including your h-file.
The linker should stop then with an error, as there are multiple (visible) defines of the same symbol.

`static const int x = 1;` creates a variable but no linker symbol, for each module including your h-file.
The linker could link the code, but as you created multiple instances of the variable with the same name, it's not sure that your code works as expected.

Btw. It's an absolutly bad idea to define a variable in a h-file, the standard way is to define them in the c-file and only to declare them in the h-file (if you really need to access them).

You use `static` when you only want to use the variable in one module, and it should be invisible to all others.
`const ...` only if you really need to access it from another module, but IMHO you should normally avoid *global* accessible variables.

**myFile.c**

```
#include "myFile.h"
const int x=1;
static const int y=2;
```

**myFile.h**

```
extern const int x;
```

Comment: Personally I don't think it's an "absolutely bad" idea to define a `static const int` in a header file. It's just that it's usually pointless in C -- for almost all purposes a `#define` or enum will do as well, and there are some things you can use the `#define`/enum for that you can't use the `static const int`, such as the size of an array member of a struct. Non-const objects in header files are probably harder to justify :-)

Comment: @Steve - Yes, I'm thinking especially at non-const objects

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  First, I don't advise you to place such definitions in a header file, but if you do then it depends on where the header file is included.  Anyway, `static` makes the variable local to the current program unit.  Here is an example:

mp1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(void);

const int x = 1;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf ("main: value of x: %d\n",x);
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

mp2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int x;

void myfunc(void)
{
    printf ("myfunc: value of x: %d\n",x);
}
```

compilation:

```
gcc -o mp mp1.c mp2.c
```

works fine.  Now change mp1.c to use `static const int x = 1;` and when we compile (actually its a link error), we get:

```
home/user1> gcc -o mp mp1.c mp2.c
/tmp/ccAeAmzp.o: In function `myfunc':
mp2.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `x'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The variable x is not visible outside of mp1.c.

The same applies to the `static` prefix to functions.